# Best way for add new properies to yaml file when I deploy new version of application

Tags: spring-boot, continuous-integration, yaml, devops, app.yaml

I have spring boot application with an `application.yaml` config. For example, it looks like this:

```
my-server
 host: localhost
 port: 8080
 time-out-in-seconds: 60
 user:
  name: Eddy
  login: Eagle
```

I start this application in five different companies. Each company has individual features: *host*, *port* and etc. For each company, I create a new `yaml` config with override some properties. For example this config for **A** company:

```
-a.yaml

my-server
     time-out-in-seconds: 120
     user:
      name: AUser
      login: SomeLogin
```

This config is near `jar` file

```
Server
 -server.jar
 -a.yaml
```

In the development process, I need to add a new property to config (**application.yaml**):

```
my-server
  host: localhost
  port: 8080
  region: foo
```

**region: foo** - is a new property. And this property must be overridden in each `company.yaml`. I need to add this property to `a.yaml(region: foo)`, `b.yaml(region: bar)` and to other.

All this complicates the update. In each deploy, I need to remember are there any new fields in the config or not. And if there is - I need to add this property to each `company.yaml`. I can randomly miss some property.

Is there some mechanism to do it? Somehow automate? Merge, versions or etc?

Comment: well for this deployment guide should be written. I can't think of automation for this. Just create your local evnironment with filled property and then use all other environments without filled property so application fails to start when property is not filled.

Comment: If with "merge" you mean YAML's language independent merge feature: no that won't work over multiple YAML documents, let alone when those documents are in different files. I suggest you programmatically (re-)generate the YAML (from YAML input) that is extremely simple to do with python.

Comment: the problem is that man who deploys an application always compares fields in previous `a.yaml` and new `a.yaml` and must determine were changes or not

Answer (score -1):

A few questions:

1. Is keeping configurations outside of the server an option?
2. Do you always have to override all yaml files or could you specify a default value and then only override those those files which need it?

If any of these two is an option, you may want to look into [spring cloud config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config) or [configrd.io](https://configrd.io). Both options offer overrides to properties.

You could point each customer's server at a different configuration profile. You could have a base configuration all customer's use. Keeping configurations outside of your server would simplify deployments and allow you to make changes without redeploying the service.